# How to change the match higlighting tags in notepad++ like sublime?

Tags: notepad++

How do I change the match highlighting Tags in notepad++, so that they have a bottom border like in the sublime?

Image Link for Match Highlighting Tags in sublime:

[image]

Comment: make a screen shot.... i dont get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

- Notepad++ does not have option of dotted underlinig of text, only solid underline.
- I also tested default tag higlighting style (named `Global Styles: Tags match higlighting`) and it seems to be ignored by the tag highlighter. It uses its own style instead.

So per current implementation, you have to go with defaults you see.